# iverilog Not Compiling Multiple Port Declarations With Multiple Bits Written In One Line

Tags: verilog, vivado, iverilog

I am trying to compile Verilog code with a testbench with the last stable version of [iverilog](https://github.com/steveicarus/iverilog) 11.0; here is an example:

```bash
iverilog -o example example.v tb_example.v
```

```
// example.v

module example(
    input [1:0] input1, [1:0] input2, // problem is here
    output [1:0] output1
    );

// ...

endmodule
```

```
// tb_example.v

module tb_example(

    );

    reg [1:0] input1;
    reg [1:0] input2;
    wire [1:0] output1;
    
    example uut(input1, input2, output1);

// ...

endmodule
```

Although there is no problem compiling in `Vivado`, the code above cannot be compiled by `iverilog` and gives this syntax error:

```bash
example.v:2: syntax error
example.v:1: Errors in port declarations.
```

When I changed the input declaration line in `example.v` to this:

```
input [1:0] input1, input2, // still one line but second bit declaration removed
```

or to this:

```
input [1:0] input1, 
input [1:0] input2, // seperate lines
```

there is no problem, and it can be compiled by `iverilog` without errors.

So, if the problem is over, why I am asking this? Because firstly, I don't understand that this can be compiling in `vivado` and not in `iverilog`, and secondly, I need to control multiple files written like this (written multiple ports with multiple bits in one line) with testbenches, and it is hard to change all of them.

Am I missing something, or does `iverilog` not support this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is legal in Verilog, but appears to be a bug with [iverilog](/questions/tagged/iverilog). It's not whether you write it on separate lines, but iverilog wants a port direction before any type declaration. So you have to use one of your workarounds or the following:

```
input [1:0] input1, input [1:0] input2,
```